# PostgreSQL SSPI authentication - FATAL: 2801: password authentication failed for user "xxx"

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication, npgsql

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL, having a fair amount of experience with MS SQL Server. One feature of PostgreSQL that has caught my eye is SSPI authentication, which I hoped would make the transition from MS SQL easier. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

For now, both server and client are running on the same Windows 7 machine, which is not a member of a domain. If I understand correctly, SSPI auth falls back from Kerberos to NTLM, so it should work without a domain - am I right?

When I try to connect (from a .NET application via Npgsql), I get an `NpgsqlException` with the message: `Fatal: 28P01: password authentication failed for user "xxx"` The message is a bit puzzling to me because I'm not using password authentication.

My `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            sspi
```

Npgsql connection string:

`Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=true;`

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it that it just doesn't work without a domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, got it. <s>I can't allow MD5 and SSPI authentication at the same time. So be it</s> **There is no "fall-through" mechanism - only the first authentication method that matches the request is attempted**. So all that was left to do was to remove the first two lines from `pg_hba.conf` and create a role with the same name as my Windows login.  What's bugging me is that what is obviously a configuration error is silently ignored, not even a warning in the log - is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Ok, I should just have RTFM: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html: "There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no record matches, access is denied."